# mongoose/mongodb deal with spamming like/unlike button and updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, express, mongoose

So whenever a user spams the like/unlike button, the updates to the database behaves in an odd way. For example:

- if the user SLOWLY presses like and unlike, the likes of a post get updated normally: post has 0 likes if disliked, post has 1 like if liked
- if the user QUICKLY presses like and unlike multiple times, the likes of a post get updated in an odd way: post has 0 likes if unliked then suddenly have 2 likes when liked.

I believe that this may have something to do with the asynchronous nature of how mongoose updates the database.

script.js:

```
$('.card-body').on('click', '#like-btn', function() {

    //unlike button is similar except that it requests /unlikePost
    $.get('/likePost', {username: username, postId: postId}, (data) => {});
})
```

I was thinking of wrapping the ajax call around a `timeout` but I'm not sure if that is the best practice.

database calls:

```
likePost: function(postId, username) {
    database.updateOne(Post, {_id: postId}, {$inc: {numberOfLikes: 1}}, (flag) => {

    })
    database.updateOne(User, {username: username}, {$addToSet: {likedPosts: postId}}, (userFlag) => {
        console.log(userFlag)
    })
},

unlikePost: function(postId, username) {
    database.updateOne(Post, {_id: postId}, {$inc: {numberOfLikes: -1}}, (flag) => {

    })
    database.updateOne(User, {username: username}, {$pull: {likedPosts: postId}}, (userFlag) => {
        console.log(userFlag)
    })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to disable the button in the UI when it is clicked, then perform the update, then enable the button again. This will make your system behave correctly when normal users use it (they will be unable to click a disabled button).

To have the system behave correctly when faced with a *determined attacker*, you need to track who voted on the server side and only allow one vote per user/IP/whatever, disallow downvoting without prior upvoting, etc. In this scenario the attacker can issue API requests directly to your application and what you do on the frontend is irrelevant.